# Button with Image and Text, ways to place the image

Tags: android, image, button

In my app, I have several buttons with little images with them. I've added them to the buttons with

```
android:drawableLeft="picture"
```

Now if my button is `fill_parent`, the picture is shown at the left, of course and my text is centered. Now my question is, is there any way to center these images or put them next to the text?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this as it help me

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // Call here getWidth() and getHeight()
    applyTextOffset(yourButton, yourButton.getWidth(),R.drawable.recents); // where R.drawable.recents is your image which you want to set as background

}
```

This the method when you can set your image near to your text

```
public void applyTextOffset(Button button, int buttonWidth, int image) {
    int textWidth = (int) button.getPaint().measureText(
            button.getText().toString());
    int padding = (buttonWidth / 2)
            - ((textWidth / 2)
                    + ((BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(image)).getBitmap().getWidth());
    button.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    button.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-padding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best way to solve your problem, but did you try to work with a layout instead of a button. For example, a LinearLayout with everything you want in the right order, and then just add a click listener to make it work like a button. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's kind of difficult to do that, because I want users to see the button immediatly if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by immediately? Using the layout here is a whole same thing with using a button, so don't worry about productivity or something else.

Comment: If I understand you well, You'd place a onClickListener on the LinearLayout and that would work? But what about the appearance of the Layout?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. A layout is just a group of views, you can combine any views you want and make them look any way you want them.

Comment: u can give any appearance to layout using android:background property